# window.location.replace is not working as expected in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, redirect, window.location

In IE browser `window.location.replace` is not working as expected. If there is any external site URL navigation is working with `window.location.replace`, but if I click back button it will come back to the previous site and again automatically redirecting to external site. Here expected result is it should come to home site only.

It seems in IE browser `location.replace` is not replacing earlier URL with new URL.

I wrote following code for redirecting to different site if result json contains absolute url.

```
var urlPattern = /^((http|https|ftp):\/\/)/;
var resultValue = result.value;

if (urlPattern.test(resultValue)) {
    //code to move to external site
    window.location.replace(resultValue);
} else {
    //code for redirecting with in the same site
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is the exact problem you are facing

Comment: Here is the flow of my application. I am in www.example.com site, I did some search operation and in result response I got external site URL i.e (www.external.com). If it is external URL, I have to navigate to that external site. Then I am navigating to www.external.com by using window.location.replace. If I click back button in that case it is coming to www.example.com site and again automatically it is going to external.com site. This case is occuring only in IE browser, in remaining browsers if we click on back button it will just come to my example.com site (i.e expected behavior) .

Comment: @ShashankAgrawal Did you understand my question now?